# Localize System Notifications for UI Tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

While working on UI Tests in *Xcode 8.0* I ran into the problem that sometimes the system sends Notifications similar to this one

[image: Location Notification]

The problem i have is: How can i be sure that i dismiss those notifications in every language? Is there a way to localize Keys like you would inside the application? 
At the moment i check for notifications inside a given handler:

```
handler = addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("alert handler") 
    { (alert: XCUIElement) -> Bool in
       if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists {
            alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

But what can i do to make this work even if the system language changes?
Thanks in advance